# Jenkins, git-plugin and Bitbucket under Windows: Authentication failed

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have setup a private Bitbucket repo which can be accessed fine by the Jenkins Git-Plugin. When I switch the repo to require authentication Jenkins complains with

```
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket/scm/test/test.git'
```

I have provided credentials in the plugin which have enough permissions to access the repo. I also can test this successfully on the command line on the jenkins server.

Repository Url in Jenkins: https://bitbucket/scm/test/test.git

If I add the credentials directly in the repository url, then the authentication works fine.

https://testuser:pa$$@bitbucket/scm/test/test.git

I currently don't understand how credentials are passed in the jenkins plugin so maybe there is something wrong with the gitconfig? Here is mine

```
[credential]
    helper = store
[core]
    editor = nano.exe
    askpass = false
```

Any suggestion how to configure git and jenkins so that I can use user authentication (username and password) via https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the user in jenkins was wrongly configured so assuming the username AND password are correctly set providing the url and selection of the correct credentials are fine

Repository Url in Jenkins: https://bitbucket/scm/test/test.git